# Transcribing .docx files to new similar but modified files with same content and style my indentations for highlighted paragraphs are distorted

Tags: python, python-docx

```
                # Transcribe source file to Target file
                #
                # print(src_paragraph.style)
                src_paragraph_format = src_paragraph.paragraph_format
                # print(src_paragraph)

                # Handle Headers/Footers
                # 
                sections = trgt_doc.sections
                section = sections[0]

                footer = section.footer
                paragraph = footer.paragraphs[0]
                paragraph.text = f'{page_number} \t\t\t {printed_time_stamp}

                # Transcribe paragraph settings
                #
                trgt_paragraph = trgt_doc.add_paragraph()
                trgt_paragraph.style.name = src_paragraph.style.name
                trgt_paragraph_format = trgt_paragraph.paragraph_format
                trgt_paragraph_format.left_indent = src_paragraph_format.left_indent
                trgt_paragraph_format.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.JUSTIFY
                trgt_paragraph_format.widow_control = True
                font = trgt_paragraph.style.font
                font.name = 'Times'
                font.size = Pt(11)

                # Transcribe source file runs.
                #
                for src_run in src_paragraph.runs:

                    trgt_run = trgt_paragraph.add_run(src_run.text)
                    trgt_paragraph_format = trgt_paragraph.paragraph_format

                    if src_run.font.highlight_color == WD_COLOR_INDEX.BRIGHT_GREEN:
                        trgt_run.font.highlight_color = WD_COLOR_INDEX.BRIGHT_GREEN
                    if src_run.bold:
                        trgt_run.bold = True
                    if src_run.italic:
                        trgt_run.italic = True
                    if src_run.underline:
                        trgt_run.underline = True
```

Indentation is as expected on target (identical with source) except the lines that are highlighted which do not conform exactly with indentation.

The process aims to get and apply the styles and attributes of the source file 
and apply them to the similar document being built along with some new additions.
The green highlight is to be exactly like that of the source file. Greene highlighting works in a few paces where only one word is highlighted but not on paragraphs.

Comment: Print out the indent values that are being assigned. It could be that some of them are `None` which may explain your results.

Comment: Looking at the code highlighting here, something doesn't seem right. (That is, apart from that humongous indent at the left.)

Comment: Indent levels are identical in both source and target files and include some `None` values where the target indents get distorted, but there is no such distortion in the source? @scanny

Comment: An indentation that is effected by a style will have no directly-applied indentation and will therefore return None on the `.format.left_indent` property.